# JQuery wait 500ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, wait

maybe someone can help me out. So i got this code, to open a textbox on my page.

```
// OPEN CERTAIN BOX
$(function() {        
    var name = ('logo');
    var toggler = (name+'-toggler');
    var div = ('#'+name+'-box');
    var toggled_class = ('no-view');        
    var plus_minus_img_id = ('#'+name+'-box-image');

    $(toggler).on('click', function(){
        $(div).toggleClass(toggled_class)
        var src = ($(plus_minus_img_id).attr('src') === 'images/plus.png')
            ? 'images/minus.png'
            : 'images/plus.png';
        $(plus_minus_img_id).attr('src', src);
    });

    var height = $(div).outerHeight();
    $(div).css('max-height', height+'px');
    $(div).toggleClass(toggled_class);
})
```

Now I would like to wait 0,5 seconds, till the `plus_minus` image changes his source, because that's how long the transition takes. Is there a possibility to do that?

I tried it with delay, but it didn't work and I don't know where to put it.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do. Firstly all you're doing is changing the source of an image, so how doe the transition take 0.5 seconds? Secondly you've not stated what you actually want to do after the delay has elapsed. We need a much clearer description of what you're trying to achieve in order to help you

Comment: damn sorry.. i'm just asking too many questions and not searching well. i just found a fitting solution for me:

            setTimeout(function(){
  $(plus_minus_img_id).attr('src', src);
}, 2000);

Comment: Search first..then ask when research exhausted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait exactly 500ms, use `setTimeout()` (or an animation library if you have animation).

If you want to wait until a resource has loaded, listen for the `load` event on the resource.

If you want to wait for a CSS transition to finish, listen for the `transitionend` event on the element.